# flexicapture processor recognize only first page of document

Tags: java, abbyy

I'm using flexicapture processor for recognizing my document. I've a case where i've a document with multiple pages i.e. a document have multiple images and each image is need to recognize.

I'm following below procedure to achieve my general task ,either one image in document or multiple image in a document;

1. create a processor
2. add document definition file or afl file
3. run recognition as   IDocument document = processor.RecognizeNextDocument();
   But when it return a document, document, it has only one page,which is the first page of document, why is it so?

On the other case, if i use project instead processor,IProject, with below procedure

1. create a project
2. get batches from project project.getBatches(),
3. add a document (that have multiple page) to batch
4. recognize them 
   The i've all pages information of document,IDocuments documents = batch.getDocuments(),

How i can achieve the same task wit processor? I want processor recognize all pages in a document and return a document with all pages in it. ?

if something is unclear, pls ask for more information. 
Please reply asap... 
Code :1 using flexicapture processor 
/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author Nitin
 *
 */

```
import java.sql.BatchUpdateException;

import com.abbyy.FCEngine.*;

public class FlexicaputreVerificationUsingProcessor {
private static Object verificationWorkSet(Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
private static void trace( String txt ) 
{
    System.out.println( txt );
}

static private String samplesFolder;
static private String projectFolder;
static private String serialNumber;
static private String dllPath;

static {

    samplesFolder = "C:\\ProgramData\\ABBYY\\SDK\\10\\FlexiCapture Engine\\Samples\\";
    projectFolder = "C:\\Users\\Nitin\\FlexicaptureTest\\flexiverificationtest" ; 

    try {

        java.io.FileInputStream file = new java.io.FileInputStream( samplesFolder + "SampleConfig\\SamplesConfig.txt" );

        java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader( new java.io.InputStreamReader( file ) );

        serialNumber = reader.readLine();

        dllPath = reader.readLine();

        file.close();

    } catch( java.io.IOException e ) {
         System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Load Engine 
    try {
            trace("Loading engine");
            IEngineLoader engineLoader= Engine.CreateEngineOutprocLoader();
            IEngine engine = engineLoader.Load(serialNumber,dllPath);

            try {

                // Create and configure FlexiCaptureProcessor
                trace("Creating and configureing FlexiCaptureProcessor");
                IFlexiCaptureProcessor processor = engine.CreateFlexiCaptureProcessor();
                processor.AddDocumentDefinitionFile( projectFolder + "\\Document_Definition_1.fcdot" );

                trace("Adding images/pdf to processor");
                final int fileCount = 1 ; 

                processor.AddImageFile(projectFolder + "\\don't upload to big .pdf");

                engine.EnableRecognitionVariants( true );

                trace("Creating Document collection");
                IDocumentsCollection documentsCollection = engine.CreateDocumentsCollection();

                trace( "Reconizing Images/pdfs..." );
                int totalErrors = 0 ; 
                for ( int iterator = 0 ; iterator<fileCount; iterator++ ){
                    trace("Recongnizing image/pdf number: " +(iterator+1));
                    IDocument document = processor.RecognizeNextDocument(); 

                    trace("Getting last processing error for checksum");
                    IProcessingError lastProcessingError = processor.GetLastProcessingError() ;

                    if ( lastProcessingError !=null)
                    {
                        String errormsg = lastProcessingError.MessageText(); 
                        totalErrors++;

                        trace("Error occured while recognizeing document, Document number: "+(iterator+1)+ " with Error msg: "+errormsg);
                        //since we are not handling error (right now) so moving to next document for recognization  
                        processor.ResumeProcessing(false);

                    }else {
                        trace("No error occured while recognization of document number : "+(iterator+1));
                    }
                    trace("Adding documents in Documents collection");
                    documentsCollection.Add(document);

                }

                if ( totalErrors == fileCount){
                    trace("Facing Error for all document while recongnization");
                    return ; 
                }

                trace("Creaing Verification session");

                try {

                    IVerificationSession verificationSession = engine.CreateVerificationSession(documentsCollection) ; 

                    try {

                        //enabling context verification
                        verificationSession.getOptions().setVerifyFields(true); 

                        //disabling group verification 
                        verificationSession.getOptions().setVerifyBaseSymbols(false);
                        verificationSession.getOptions().setVerifyExtraSymbols(false);

                        try {
                            trace("Get NextWork Set");
                            IVerificationWorkSet verificationWorkSet =  verificationSession.NextWorkSet();

                            if ( verificationWorkSet == null){
                                trace("first verificationWork set is null");
                            }else {

                                //process each work set in Verification session
                                trace("Processing Work Set");
                                while ( verificationWorkSet != null ){

                                    try{
                                        trace("Geting Verification group");
                                        //get next group for verification 
                                        IVerificationGroup verificationGroup = verificationWorkSet.NextGroup(); 

                                        if ( verificationGroup == null ){
                                            trace("First verification group is null");
                                        }else {
                                            trace("processing each group of a workset");
                                            //processing each group of a work set
                                            while ( verificationGroup!= null){
                                                int verificationObjectInAGroupCount =  verificationGroup.getCount(); 
                                                trace("Total number of verification object: " +verificationObjectInAGroupCount);

                                                for ( int iterator = 0; iterator<verificationObjectInAGroupCount; iterator++){
                                                    trace ( "getting and Processing "+(iterator +1 ) + " verification object of A group");

                                                    //getting verification object 
                                                    IVerificationObject verificationObject = verificationGroup.getElement(iterator);
                                                    if ( verificationObject == null){
                                                        trace("verification object is null");
                                                    }else {
                                                        if ( verificationObject.getType() == VerificationObjectTypeEnum.VOT_Group ) {
                                                            IGroupVerificationObject groupVerificationObject = verificationObject.AsGroupVerificationObject(); 

                                                            if ( groupVerificationObject == null){
                                                                System.out.println("group verification object is null ");
                                                            }


                                                        }else if ( verificationObject.getType() == VerificationObjectTypeEnum.VOT_Context) {
                                                            IContextVerificationObject  contextVerificationObject = verificationObject.AsContextVerificationObject(); 




                                                            if ( contextVerificationObject == null){
                                                                trace("ContextVerification object is null");
                                                            }else {
                                                                IField field = contextVerificationObject.getField(); 
                                                                if ( field == null){
                                                                    trace("field getting null");
                                                                }else {
                                                                    System.out.println(" field full name: " +field.getFullName() + "\n Name: " +field.getName());

                                                                    IFieldValue fieldValue = field.getValue();
                                                                    if ( fieldValue == null){
                                                                        trace("Field Value is Null");
                                                                        }else {

                                                                    trace ( "getting text from field value");
                                                                        IText text = fieldValue.getAsText() ; 
                                                                        if ( text == null){
                                                                            trace("text getting null in field value");
                                                                        }else {


                                                                            int wordCount = text.getRecognizedWordsCount() ; 
                                                                            trace("recognized word count: "+wordCount);

                                                                            //getting words from text 
                                                                            for ( int wordIndex = 0 ; wordIndex<wordCount; wordIndex++ ){
                                                                                trace ("processing word number :" +wordIndex);

                                                                                IRecognizedWordInfo recognizedWordInfo = engine.CreateRecognizedWordInfo()  ; 

                                                                                if ( recognizedWordInfo == null){
                                                                                    trace("Can't create recognizedWordInfo object using engine");
                                                                                }else {
                                                                                    text.GetRecognizedWord(wordIndex, -1, recognizedWordInfo);

                                                                                    //getting characters from word
                                                                                    for (int characterIndex = 0 ; characterIndex<recognizedWordInfo.getText().length(); characterIndex++ ){
                                                                                        trace("processing character number : " +characterIndex);

                                                                                        IRecognizedCharacterInfo recognizedCharacterInfo = engine.CreateRecognizedCharacterInfo(); 
                                                                                        if ( recognizedCharacterInfo == null) {
                                                                                            trace("can't create recognizedCharacterInfo object");
                                                                                        }else {
                                                                                            recognizedWordInfo.GetRecognizedCharacter(characterIndex, -1, recognizedCharacterInfo);

                                                                                            System.out.println(" Character: " + recognizedCharacterInfo.getCharacter());
                                                                                            System.out.println(" Confidence level : " +recognizedCharacterInfo.getCharConfidence());
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                        System.out.println(" Field Value : " +fieldValue.getAsString());
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                trace("Geting next Verification group");
                                                verificationGroup = verificationWorkSet.NextGroup();
                                            }

                                        }

                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                        trace("Exception occured in getting next work group");
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    trace("Get next worksets");
                                    //get next work set
                                    verificationWorkSet =  verificationSession.NextWorkSet();

                                }
                            }

                        }catch (Exception e){

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }finally {
                        trace("closing Verification object");
                        verificationSession.Close();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    trace("Exception occured in creating verification sessions");
                }



            }catch (Exception e){
                trace ("Exception occured in");
            }

    }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
            trace("unloading Engine");
            Engine.Unload();
        }



}
```

}

Code : 2 using project

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.BatchUpdateException;

import com.abbyy.FCEngine.*;

public class VerificationStep {
//same as above

    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        // Load Engine 
        try {
                trace("Loading engine");
                IEngineLoader engineLoader= Engine.CreateEngineOutprocLoader();
                IEngine engine = engineLoader.Load(serialNumber,dllPath);

                try{
                    IProject project = engine.OpenProject( projectFolder + "\\flexitest.fcproj" );

                    try {
                        IBatch batch = null ; 
                        trace( "Creating Batch..." );
                        IBatches batchs = project.getBatches(); 
                        if (batchs == null || batchs.getCount() == 0){
                            batch = project.getBatches().AddNew("TestBatch");
                        }
                        batch = batchs.getElement(0);
                        assert(batch == null);

                        try{
                            trace("opening batch");
                            batch.Open();

                            trace( "Adding pdfs..." );
                     batch.AddImage(projectFolder + "\\don't upload to big .pdf");

                            trace( "Reconizing pdfs..." );
                            batch.Recognize(null, RecognitionModeEnum.RM_ReRecognizeAll,null);

                            trace("Creating Verification object");
                            try {   
                                IVerificationSession verificationSession = project.StartVerification(null); 

                                try {

                                    //enabling context verification
                                    verificationSession.getOptions().setVerifyFields(true); 

                                    //disabling group verification 
                                    verificationSession.getOptions().setVerifyBaseSymbols(false);
                                    verificationSession.getOptions().setVerifyExtraSymbols(false);

                                    try {
                                        trace("Get NextWork Set");
                                        IVerificationWorkSet verificationWorkSet =  verificationSession.NextWorkSet();

                                        if ( verificationWorkSet == null){
                                            trace("first verificationWork set is null");
                                        }else {

                                            //process each work set in Verification session
                                            trace("Processing Work Set");
                                            while ( verificationWorkSet != null ){

                                                try{
                                                    trace("Geting Verification group");
                                                    //get next group for verification 
                                                    IVerificationGroup verificationGroup = verificationWorkSet.NextGroup(); 

                                                    if ( verificationGroup == null ){
                                                        trace("First verification group is null");
                                                    }else {
                                                        trace("processing each group of a workset");
                                                        //processing each group of a work set
                                                        while ( verificationGroup!= null){
                                                            int verificationObjectInAGroupCount =  verificationGroup.getCount(); 
                                                            trace("Total number of verification object: " +verificationObjectInAGroupCount);

                                                            for ( int iterator = 0; iterator<verificationObjectInAGroupCount; iterator++){
                                                                trace ( "getting and Processing "+(iterator +1 ) + " verification object of A group");

                                                                //getting verification object 
                                                                IVerificationObject verificationObject = verificationGroup.getElement(iterator);
                                                                if ( verificationObject == null){
                                                                    trace("verification object is null");
                                                                }else {
                                                                    if ( verificationObject.getType() == VerificationObjectTypeEnum.VOT_Group ) {
                                                                        IGroupVerificationObject groupVerificationObject = verificationObject.AsGroupVerificationObject(); 

                                                                        if ( groupVerificationObject == null){
                                                                            System.out.println("group verification object is null ");
                                                                        }


                                                                    }else if ( verificationObject.getType() == VerificationObjectTypeEnum.VOT_Context) {
                                                                        IContextVerificationObject  contextVerificationObject = verificationObject.AsContextVerificationObject(); 



                                                                        if ( contextVerificationObject == null){
                                                                            trace("ContextVerification object is null");
                                                                        }else {
                                                                            IField field = contextVerificationObject.getField(); 
                                                                            if ( field == null){
                                                                                trace("field getting null");
                                                                            }else {
                                                                                System.out.println(" field full name: " +field.getFullName() + "\n Name: " +field.getName());

                                                                                IFieldValue fieldValue = field.getValue();
                                                                                if ( fieldValue == null){
                                                                                    trace("Field Value is Null");
                                                                                    }else {
                                                                                        trace ( "getting text from field value");
                                                                                    IText text = fieldValue.getAsText() ; 
                                                                                    if ( text == null){
                                                                                        trace("text getting null in field value");
                                                                                    }else {

                                                                                        int wordCount = text.getRecognizedWordsCount() ; 
                                                                                        trace("recognized word count: "+wordCount);

                                                                                        //getting words from text 
                                                                                        for ( int wordIndex = 0 ; wordIndex<wordCount; wordIndex++ ){
                                                                                            trace ("processing word number :" +wordIndex);

                                                                                            IRecognizedWordInfo recognizedWordInfo = engine.CreateRecognizedWordInfo()  ; 

                                                                                            if ( recognizedWordInfo == null){
                                                                                                trace("Can't create recognizedWordInfo object using engine");
                                                                                            }else {
                                                                                                text.GetRecognizedWord(wordIndex, -1, recognizedWordInfo);

                                                                                                //getting characters from word
                                                                                                for (int characterIndex = 0 ; characterIndex<recognizedWordInfo.getText().length(); characterIndex++ ){
                                                                                                    trace("processing character number : " +characterIndex);

                                                                                                    IRecognizedCharacterInfo recognizedCharacterInfo = engine.CreateRecognizedCharacterInfo(); 
                                                                                                    if ( recognizedCharacterInfo == null) {
                                                                                                        trace("can't create recognizedCharacterInfo object");
                                                                                                    }else {
                                                                                                        recognizedWordInfo.GetRecognizedCharacter(characterIndex, -1, recognizedCharacterInfo);

                                                                                                        System.out.println(" Character: " + recognizedCharacterInfo.getCharacter());
                                                                                                        System.out.println(" Confidence level : " +recognizedCharacterInfo.getCharConfidence());
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    System.out.println(" Field Value : " +fieldValue.getAsString());
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }

                                                            verificationGroup = verificationWorkSet.NextGroup();
                                                        }

                                                    }

                                                }catch (Exception e){

                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }

                                               //get next work set
                                                verificationWorkSet =  verificationSession.NextWorkSet();

                                            }
                                        }

                                    }catch (Exception e){

                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }finally {
                                   verificationSession.Close();
                                }
                            }catch (Exception e){

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            trace ("Getting Documents");
                            IDocuments documents = batch.getDocuments(); 

                            trace ("Getting Fields and printing");
                            for ( int j = 0 ; j < documents.getCount(); j++){
                                trace ("Getting documnets:" +(j+1));

                                IDocument document = documents.getElement(j);
                                IDocumentDefinition definition = document.getDocumentDefinition();
                                assert( definition != null );
                                assert( document.getPages().getCount() == 1 );


                                trace( "DocumentType: " + document.getDocumentDefinition().getName() );

                                try {
                                    trace("opening document");
                                    document.Open(true);
                                    IFields fields = document.getSections().Item( 0 ).getChildren();

                                    for( int i = 0; i < fields.getCount(); i++ ) {
                                        IField field = fields.getElement( i );
                                        trace( field.getName() + ": " + 
                                                                ( field.getValue() != null ? field.getValue().getAsString() : "." ) );
                                    }
                                }finally {
                                    trace("closing document");
                                    document.Close(true);
                                }
                            }
                        }finally {
                                trace("Closing Batch");
                                batch.Close();
                        }

                }catch (Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Exception in creating Batch");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    trace("closing project");

                    project.Close();
                }

                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Exception occured while loading project");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Exception occured while loading engine");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
                trace("unloading Engine");
                Engine.Unload();

            }

    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got my solution, actually it recognize correctly, i'm handling them wrong way...